# Вычисление суммы повторов значений во всей таблице. И запись этих сумм в новый столбец, напротив каждого повторяющегося значения

Tags: sql, sql-server

Еще одна задача на MS SQL. 
Имеется таблица Table1 с уникальным Id и неуникальными значениями в поле Value:

|ID | Value |
|1 | 155 |
|2 | 155 |
|3 | 182 |
|4 | 182 |
|5 | 182 |
|6 | 182 |
|7 | 182 |
|8 | 137 |
|9 | 147 |

Нужно сделать выборку SELECT * From где появиться третий столбец as TotalSum,
где на каждое значение Value будет выставлена общая сумма повторов этого значения Value во всей таблице.

Вывод должен получиться таким:

|ID | Value |TotalSum
|1  | 155   |  2
|2  | 155   |  2
|3  | 182   |  5
|4  | 182   |  5
|5  | 182   |  5
|6  | 182   |  5
|7  | 182   |  5
|8  | 137   |  1
|9  | 147   |  1

Comment: "..Нужно сделать..." - кому нужно ? Свой вариант решения есть?

Comment: Нужно мне, был бы вариант решения, не стал бы вопросы такие задавать :) Я думал сначала выбрать общую таблицу с количеством повторов на каждое значение. А потом как то используя LEFT JOIN вывести такие результаты, как в конце вопроса.

Comment: Ну так напишите свои соображения в тексте вопроса, чтобы можно было отделить бездельника от человека, которому следует помогать

Comment: Я привел аналогию на простом примере из своей задачи только в том моменте, где никак не получилось написать запрос. Убрал все лишнее и написал только про этот момент.

Comment: Кстати, я не могу снять минус (кнопка блокирована), пока не будут внесены изменения в текст вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В MS SQL Server, начиная с 2008 версии, можно воспользоваться оконной функцией:

```
select id, value, count(id) over (partition by value) as TotalSum
from Table1
```

[Оконные функции в Transact-SQL и использование OVER:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/ms189461(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: емнип с 2008го прокатит

Comment: Прекрасно работает, то что надо! Спасибо!